# Finding unique numbers in Column B compared to the set in Column A: Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, unique, counting, countif

I have one sheet with 2 columns of ID numbers. I need a formula that will compare the numbers in Column B (about 50 of them) to the numbers in Column A (about 1000 of them). In Column C, I'd like to return the numbers that are in B but not in A.

I know I can run a duplicate search by hand, but am looking for a formula to take care of it instead. Also, highlighting is not helpful in this instance.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(B1:B; NOT(COUNTIF(A1:A; B1:B))))
```

[image]